# How to create a unit test for dictionary C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dictionary, nunit

I would like to make an rpn calculator and create unit test using nunit for the dictionary to test operations, but i don't know how to make it.

```
    static Stack<double> stack { get; set; } = new Stack<double>();

    static Dictionary<string, Action> operators = new Dictionary<string, Action>
    {
        ["+"] = () => { stack.Push(stack.Pop() + stack.Pop()); },
        ["-"] = () => { var x = stack.Pop(); stack.Push(stack.Pop() - x); },
        ["*"] = () => { stack.Push(stack.Pop() * stack.Pop()); },
        ["/"] = () => { var x = stack.Pop(); if (x == 0) throw new DivideByZeroException(); stack.Push(stack.Pop() / x); },
        ["clr"] = () => { stack.Clear(); },
        ["!"] = () => { var x = stack.Pop(); stack.Push(x == 0 ? 1 : 0); },
        ["!="] = () => { stack.Push(stack.Pop() == stack.Pop() ? 0 : 1); },
        ["%"] = () => { var x = stack.Pop(); stack.Push(stack.Pop() % x); },
        ["++"] = () => { var x = stack.Pop(); x++; stack.Push(x); },
        ["--"] = () => { var x = stack.Pop(); x--; stack.Push(x); },
}
```

EDIT: Executing is like

```
 while (true)
        {
            Display();
            var readLine = Console.ReadLine();               

            var tokens = readLine.Split(" ").Where(t => t != string.Empty).ToArray();
            foreach (var token in tokens)
            {
                try
                {
                    operators[token].Invoke();
                }
                catch(KeyNotFoundException)
                {
                    stack.Push(double.Parse(token));
                }
            }               
        }
```

Comment: Unit tests are created to test something. They don't exist by themselves. What do you want to test? Whether the dictionary contains all operators? Whether each of those does what it's supposed to do? Each case requires a different test.

Comment: Unit Tests are used to primarily test functions not variables, however I think that you want to test the values of your Dictionary and check if the correct Action is returned or executed, I suggest you read up on nUnit [Theory] and [DataPoint] annotations (https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/attributes/theory.html)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what it's supposed to do. I would only like to test the operations to see if they works fine

Comment: Style note: Using a `try`/`catch` for program flow is a bad practice; it should be used for handling errors. In your case, you can use `if (operators.ContainsKey(token)) {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put `stack` and `operators` as `private` fields in some `class` called for example `CalculatingService` . after that you should create `public` method `Calculate(...)`, which will `return` calculated value:

```cs
public class CalculatingService : ICalculatingService
{
    private readonly Stack<double> stack { get; set; }
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<double>> operators;

    public CalculatingService() 
    {
        stack = new Stack<double>();
        InitDictionary();
    }
    
    public double Calculate(string @operator) =>
        operators[@operator].Invoke();
    
    public void ClearData() => stack.Clear();
    
    private void InitDictionary() => operators = new Dictionary<string, Func<double>>
    {
        ["+"] = () => stack.Pop() + stack.Pop(),
        ["-"] = () => { var x = stack.Pop(); return stack.Pop() - x; },
        ["*"] = () => stack.Pop() * stack.Pop(),
        ["/"] = () => { var x = stack.Pop(); if (x == 0) throw new DivideByZeroException(); return stack.Pop() / x; },
        ["!"] = () => { var x = stack.Pop(); return x == 0 ? 1 : 0; },
        ["!="] = () => stack.Pop() == stack.Pop() ? 0 : 1,
        ["%"] = () => { var x = stack.Pop(); return stack.Pop() % x; },
        ["++"] = () => { var x = stack.Pop(); x++; return x; },
        ["--"] = () => { var x = stack.Pop(); x--; return x; } 
    };
}
```

now you can create test methods for all methods in `CalculatingService`. You can test `Calculate(...)` by writing x test methods for x operators. I dunno, how do u manage `stack` - you have to write additional `public` methods in `CalculatingService` for `stack` management like I wrote `ClearData()`.

Comment: ok but how i can manage with stack,Push(...) because throwing error like is not convertible to the delegate return type, to execute. Its simple console app, main loop is like `ReadLine()` then divide with spaces and match with dictionary key

Comment: This is a great description of how to improve the code, but it would be good if it included some actual unit test examples.

Comment: @szut, now I saw your edition of post and... did you even run this code? Let say you wrote "3 + 5" in console. "3" will be pushed to `stack` and "+" will invoke function responsible for adding value. However since you had run `stack.Pop()` twice, your program threw `InvalidOperationException`, because you had have only "3" in `stack`.

Comment: @ScottHannen, firstly i don't know, what library will be used for tests and secondly I assume that OP understands, how to use test framework, so I just pointed out methodology for testing : )

Comment: @ScottHannen, i saw "nunit" tag now, so first point doesn't apply : D

Comment: @BartłomiejStasiak what about when I want to remove last element on stack, I mean `["drop"]=()=>stack.Pop()` Pop always returning a value so its not possible I guess.

Comment: `Pop()` doesn't always return value, because when you use it, you remove first object from top of stack, so if you do `Pop()` as many times as number of objects in `stack`, `stack` will be empty. After that next `Pop()` will throw `InvalidOperationException`, since there are no longer any object to remove. `Peek()` on other hand doesn't remove object from `stack`. You are right that you can't remove only last object from `stack`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by making it non-static. Otherwise each test will affect the next unless you clear the stack. It's easier if you can just have `calculator = new Calculator()` in each test.

From the look of it operations are sent to the calculator as strings. It's not shown, but I'm guessing that the digits are also. That's not clear.

In order to make sure your calculator works, presumably you'll want to send it some numbers and operations and make sure that when it's done the calculator has the correct result. One way to do that is with parameterized tests. That is, you write one test but send it multiple sets of inputs.

Here's an NUnit example. Please remember that I don't know the exact details of how your calculator works, so this is more of a pointer and not a perfect example.

First I had to create a basic `Calculator` class, because it's much harder to write unit tests with a static class. (But wait, your stack and dictionary are missing! More on that.)

```cs
public class Calculator 
{
    public string DisplayedResult { get; }
    public void SendInput(string input)
    {

    }
}
```

The idea is that `SendInput` is like pressing a button, and when you press a button `DisplayedResult` changes. So if you press "2 + 2 2 =" it would display "24." If you press "5 / 0 =" it might display "error". If there's a "clear" button then "5 / 0 = C 2 + 2 =" might display "4". (First there was an error, then it was cleared, then there was another operation.)

Now we can write a parameterized NUnit test like this:

```cs
[Test]
[TestCase("2 + 2 2 =","24")]
[TestCase("5 / 0 =", "error")]
[TestCase("5 / 0 = C 2 + 2 =", "4")]
public void Calculator_Displays_Expected_Results(string input, string expectedResult)
{
    var inputsToSend = input.Split(' ');
    var calculator = new Calculator();
    foreach (var inputToSend in inputsToSend)
    {
        calculator.SendInput(inputToSend);
    }
    Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, calculator.DisplayedResult);
}
```

Each test case has an input - a series of operations separated by strings. That makes it easy to create each test case. It also has an expected result. What do we expect the calculator to display?

The test sends the inputs and verifies that you get the expected result. You could separate it into multiple tests, or you could have one big test with lots of cases. You can write as many tests as you want. You could add another argument with a description of what's being tested.

Two important details:

The design has to take testing into account. Static classes are harder to test. Also, it's easier to test if the class exposes an interface that makes it easy to test - inputs and outputs. If something is hard to test it often represents a difficulty with the design. So it's normal that we'll adjust to a design that's easier to test.

What about the dictionary and the stack? If that's how you want to implement the calculator, that's fine - you can add that. Perhaps the `SendInput` method interacts with them and updates the `DisplayedResult` as needed.

What's important is that the tests won't be tied to that implementation detail. What if you change your mind and don't use a stack and a dictionary, and you write completely different code to handle those operations? The tests will still be exactly as valid. As long as your implementation works, whatever it is, the tests will pass.